# Interactive map of Canada with latitude and longitude markers

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

Is there the easy way to have interactive map of Canada (based on provinces first), to basically be able to click on province, then to zoom in selected province, and show markers on that region based on latitude and longitude?

Initially I though I can use google maps API for that, but it would be too much extra codding to draw province boundaries and to add all the events, etc. so I'm looking for some alternative which might save me some time so I don't have to worry about UI part that much. Any suggestion?

Comment: [FusionTables map of Canada](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test//v3_FusionTables_CountryBrowser_encryptedID.html?country=Canada)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could recommend leaflet: [Leaflet](http://leafletjs.com/)

Here is an example of an interactive map: [Interactive Map Example](http://leafletjs.com/examples/choropleth/)

I sometimes get boundary datas from (but there are for sure a dozent others) : [Boundary Provider](https://osm.wno-edv-service.de/boundaries/)

You can get a json from the boundary provider an use leaflet javascript library to fullfill your project. Leaflet is really easy to get into and many code-snippets can be found on the internet to have a quick nice looking output.

Comment: Thank you, this was exactly what I was looking for! Works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Leaflet](http://leafletjs.com/).

> Leaflet is the leading open-source JavaScript library for mobile-friendly interactive maps. Weighing just about 38 KB of JS, it has all the mapping features most developers ever need.

I have personally used Leaflet in many R projects and it's the best JavaScript library for interactive maps manipulation out there.